# HttpPost from android not working

Tags: php, android

From android app i want to send some data . This data should be displayed in website. Currently i'm trying in localhost using XAMPP.

> Main Activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button sendButton  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new NetworkOperation().execute();
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "response", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}
```

> Another class

```
public class NetworkOperation extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.104/Project/script.php");
    try{
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id","somevalue"));
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        Log.d("Http Response:", (response.getEntity()).toString());
    }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("clientprotocolexception");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("IOexception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
    return null;
}
```

> Included in Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

> I have php script file as follows

```
<?php
$error = 'Not received';
$result =  (isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : $error);
echo $result;
```

?>

Comment: Is this calling that script file ? Just display anything in script file and check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending the `HTTP POST` request, but not processing the data it returns. This would be an example on how to wait for the response from the server side, I've tried to comment the relevant parts so it should be easy to understand.

```
HttpResponse response = null;

try {
  // Fill in the POST pair you want to sent to the server
  final List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mykey", "myvalue"));
  httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

  // Send the request
  response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
}
catch (final ClientProtocolException e) { ... }
catch (final IOException e) { ... }

// Now you have to process the response    
InputStream ips;
try {
  ips = response.getEntity().getContent();
  final BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ips, "UTF-8"));

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  String s;
  while (true) {
    s = buf.readLine();
    if ((s == null) || (s.length() == 0))
      break;
    sb.append(s);
  }

  buf.close();
  ips.close();

  Log.d("JSONResponse", "My response from the server is: " + sb.toString());
} 
catch (IllegalStateException e1) { } 
catch (IOException e1) { }

if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
  try { throw new Exception(response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase()); } 
  catch (final Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your instant reply. It worked. It displayed the post data in LOG. But i want to display in website using php script.

Comment: I can't understand what you want to do. Can you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: From android app i want to send some data . This data should be displayed in website. Currently i'm trying in localhost using XAMPP